# Securing a form

Tags: forms, security, http

I'm looking for a method of securing a form. The problem is that the page on which the form will be displayed will be deployed on a CDN and will be  static. A javascript on that page will be collecting the form data and sending it to a handler using Ajax. Both the static HTML page and the Post handler will be running on the same domain.

Is there a smart method of preventing someone from taking my javascript and just putting it on his HTML page and sending data from it to my POST Handler ?

I can't white-list IPs cause pages will be distributed on CDN and it is impossible to predict them.

HTTP Referrer can be easily faked.

CORS is client enforced and therefore can by easily bypassed.

Is there anything else that can be reliably done ?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to secure this scenario is through authorization/authentication.  Either that particular request from your javascript must be authorized, or the entire session must be from an authenticated user.  Inherently, the browser client is *always* considered insecure, and security is enforced on the server side.

Comment: The only way to secure your static html page is by attaching some kind of token to a request which is valid only for exact user, or only for one use. If you control how people get on your static page, you could set a cookie on a domain for example.